# AWS Cloudformation and ECS with docker app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Im looking for help because I failed to find any kind of solution to my problem. I am a beginner with the use of AWS and the documentation and examples are tooo way overheating my brain to get starting with something. I simply look at the docs and examples and can't do anything because there is so much things...
Basically what I need is to be able to deploy my containerized application to the EC2 and access it through the web. I would like to use a cloudformation template to deploy ECS and run my app on it but I really can't find a way how to write the template.
Everything should be done from within the scripts aka programmatically.

The working solution would be:
using https://github.com/Nordstrom/cfn  to deploy the cloudformation template where it deploys my app and run it without using the AWS WEB UI. The biggest problem to me is the template. I simply can't understand the syntax and how to write it properly to deploy an app.

Comment: It might be easier to start with [Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html) or even [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html).

Comment: is it possible to introduce the public images like from the docker hub  rather than pushing to ECS registry ??

Comment: ecs can use images on docker hub: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html

Answer (score 7):

AWS have something called "reference architecture" for many of their products, including ECS.

https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation

It's a collection of CloudFormation templates that launch everything you need to have an ECS cluster working with a basic web service. This is an incredibly great starter for beginners as you can launch a Stack using their templates and gradually customize it for your needs.

Comment: I found some starting kit templates and I was able to do Networking and Service stack deploy which is what I was looking for ! thanks for all the help